# How get data and return as string in function in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table and when i make select i have results with two records. So now is ok. This result is INT. I want create function when i get each one of this value and add as string and return as string. Now i have result. What is wrong ?

### pno

123
873

and after function i want

### pno

123, 873, etc etc

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        declare i_myfield int;
        declare abc int;
        declare mycur cursor for SELECT pno FROM ptable WHERE no = no_id;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        set abc = 0;
        open mycur;

        read_loop: loop
            fetch mycur into i_myfield;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            SET abc = abc + CONVERT(i_myfield, CHAR(50));

        END loop;
    close mycur;
    return pono;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having your database do this for you (instead of looping through your cursor, which can be expensive):

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pno) FROM ptable WHERE no = no_id;
```

That replicates all of this code in one simple statement.

Comment: No worries. We've all reinvented the wheel once or twice ;)